# Filling in missing data in SQL table with overlapping groups

Tags: sql, database, join

I have some analytics data where a single activity stream for visitor our a website, where for part of the trace there is an id and later on the identifier is a different value. How can I using SQL pad the data so that it is complete.

```
 id1 | id2 |   timestamp 
-----+-----+---------------------
null |   3 |  123450 
null |   3 |  123451 
null |   3 |  123452 
   5 |   3 |  123453 
   5 |   3 |  123454 
   5 |null |  123455 
   5 |null |  123456 
   5 |null |  123457 
...
null |   8 |  123450 
null |   8 |  123451 
null |   8 |  123452 
   9 |   8 |  123453 
   9 |   8 |  123454 
   9 |null |  123455 
   9 |null |  123456 
   9 |null |  123457 
...
```

The two sections above are part of the same group, and I know that because they essentially  some point stops recording the id2.

I want a query or sql and intermediate tables that would enabled me to populate the null values above so that I have:

```
 id1 | id2 |   timestamp 
-----+-----+---------------------
   5 |   3 |  123450 
   5 |   3 |  123451 
   5 |   3 |  123452 
   5 |   3 |  123453 
   5 |   3 |  123454 
   5 |   3 |  123455 
   5 |   3 |  123456 
   5 |   3 |  123457 
...
   9 |   8 |  123450 
   9 |   8 |  123451 
   9 |   8 |  123452 
   9 |   8 |  123453 
   9 |   8 |  123454 
   9 |   8 |  123455 
   9 |   8 |  123456 
   9 |   8 |  123457 
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there will be one `id2` corresponding to one `id1` other than null and 
only one `id1` corresponding to one `id2` other than null

```
select a.id1, a.id2, b.timestamp
from  (
  select min(id1) id1, id2
  from tbl
  where id1 is not null and id2 is not null
  group by id2
) a right join tbl b
on (a.id1 = b.id1) OR (a.id2 = b.id2)
```

Comment: `a.id1 = b.id1 || a.id2 = b.id2` is invalid standard SQL. And besides: concatenating the two id values doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name can you explain why its invalid... Is it because id(s) hva null values...

Comment: Because you essentially have `where expression1 = expression2 = expression3`. If at all, you would need to put one pair of the expressions between parentheses, e.g. `(expression1 = expression2) = expression3` but then `expression3` has to be a `boolean` value (which `id2` most likely isn't)

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that `id1` and `id2` occur in unique pairs *and each id is never with any other values*, then you can simply use window functions:

```
select coalesce(id1, max(id1) over (partition by id2)) as id1,
       coalesce(id2, max(id2) over (partition by id1)) as id2,
       timestamp
from t;
```

Without this assumption, the question is not well formed and does not have a specific answer.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=62985c7688a1a4fbe6885b9991f04c82) is a db<>fiddle